# APEX 20.1 Change Popup LOV based on Page Item

Tags: oracle, dynamic, oracle-apex

i need a workaround where the List of Values change dynamically of the Popup LOV based on a Page Item. For instance when the Page Item holds the value 1 then the values of the POPUP LOV should be 10, 11, 12, 13 and so on. When the Page Item holds the value 2 then it should be 20, 21, 22 and so on. I need this not for numbers but for the different departments with its divisions.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to set up the Department field to be a cascading LOV this way whenever the Division field changes, the Department field will update as well.

I've built an [example application](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/adptest/r/ej-demo/cascading-lov-demo) for you to see how it would work.

[image: APEX Developer Example]

Comment: Hi EJ, thank you very much for the proposed solution. It worked for me smoothly. I have one more addition where the admin has the right to change the names of the Popup LOV value items. For instance change DEPT 100 to DEPT 101. Any idea to do this.